# How to test if a mail has two points after @

Tags: sql, postgresql, oracle

In my case, I want to allow mails with two or more dots after `@` like `test@test1.test2.com`.

I want to do it in SQL and test it in Oracle and PostgreSQL.

If anyone knows how to do it in SQL with a regex, please help.

I have already done this - is this correct ?

```
[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+[.][A-Za-z]
```

Comment: Should we create a test coverage for your development? What is your actual question? Here are [some examples](https://regex101.com/r/EeRbsH/1)

Comment: sure this part `0-9._` work? the `.` (dot) especially. afaik, dot in regex is a token to match any single character.

Comment: Why not just use LIKE '%@%.%.%' ?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one option: count number of dots after `@` sign:

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'test@test1.test2.com.' from dual)
  3  select regexp_count(substr(col, instr(col, '@')), '\.') number_of_dots
  4  from test;

NUMBER_OF_DOTS
--------------
             3

SQL>
```

---

Use it as e.g.

```
SQL> with test (col) as
  2    (select 'test@test1.test2.com.' from dual union all
  3     select 'another@test.com'      from dual
  4    )
  5  select col,
  6    case when regexp_count(substr(col, instr(col, '@')), '\.') >= 2 then 'OK'
  7         else 'wrong'
  8    end result
  9  from test;

COL                   RESULT
--------------------- --------------------
test@test1.test2.com. OK
another@test.com      wrong

SQL>
```